# How do KendoUI's new mapping features compare to GISCloud or other solutions?

Tags: vector, kendo-ui, mapping, gis, arcgis

Taking a look at [KendoUI's Map API](http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/map/api.html) today, I'm curious about if this represents any real improvement over existing technologies.  Taking a look at their [data feed](http://demos.kendoui.com/content/dataviz/map/countries-users.geo.json), it appears that this is all vector based - great!

So would this offer any real improvement over something like [GISCloud](http://www.giscloud.com/) using ArcGIS or any other mapping base?